# how do i Load a player's appearance into a NPC when a Player Joins

Tags: scripting, roblox

so my game is 1 player per server and so i want the NPC To change into the players character. But the thing is im not good at coding/scripting at all. So if anyone can help me for this Roblox Script I'll be more than happy.

Code:

players = game:GetService("Players") players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player) player.CharacterAdded:connect(function(character) local copy = character:Clone() copy.Parent = game.Workspace --put the clone into the physical environment local game = game end end)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)! You might wanna take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We need you to provide code you have tried, also we help people with their code not code it for them.

Comment: Oh okay I have tried this code though:

Comment: players = game:GetService("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
 player.CharacterAdded:connect(function(character)
  local copy = character:Clone()
  copy.Parent = game.Workspace --put the clone into the physical environment

  local game = game
 end
end)

Comment: please edit your question to include the code sample. Posting code in comments makes it very hard to read.